# Реализация stl совместимых итераторов

Tags: c++, stl

Хочу реализовать список который предоставляет stl-совместимые итераторы, то есть те которые можно использовать в stl алгоритмах. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
public:
    using UsingType = T;

    Node(const UsingType& v) : value(v), previous(nullptr), next(nullptr)
    {
    }
    Node(const UsingType& v, const std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>>& p, const std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>>& n) : value(v), previous(p), next(n) {}

    UsingType value;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>> previous;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>> next;
};

template<class T> class LinkedList;

template<class T>
class Iterator
{
public:
    using UsingType = T;
    friend class LinkedList<UsingType>;


    Iterator(const std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>>& node) : _node(node)
    {
    }

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
        _node = _node->next;
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return _node->value;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Iterator& it)
    {
        return _node != it._node;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>> _node;
};



template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    using SizeType = unsigned int;
    using UsingType = T;

public:
    LinkedList() : _size(0), _begin(nullptr), _end(nullptr) 
    {
    }

    void pushBack(const UsingType& value)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>> node = std::make_shared<Node<UsingType>>(value);

        if (_size == 0)
        {
            _end = std::make_shared<Node<UsingType>>( UsingType() );

            _begin = node;
            _begin->next = _end;
            _end->previous = _begin;
        }
        else
        {
            node->previous = _end->previous;
            node->previous->next = node;
            node->next = _end;
            _end->previous = node;
        }
        ++_size;
    }

    Iterator<UsingType> begin()
    {
        return Iterator(_begin);
    }

    Iterator<UsingType> end()
    {
        return Iterator(_end);
    }


private:
    SizeType _size;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>> _begin;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<UsingType>> _end;
};
```

Мне здесь не нравится вставка элемента, т.к. проверяется условие на пустой контейнер, которое будет верно только при первой вставке. Этого можно избежать если сразу, при создании контейнера, создавать два элемента которые будут располагаться перед началом и перед концом, но мне кажется это будет еще хуже.

Я смотрел стандартную реализацию, и, насколько я смог понять, там точно не происходит динамического выделения памяти для пустого контейнера и вставка элемента выполняется одинакового как для пустого контейнера так и не для пустого.

Вопрос: подскажите как нормально реализовать stl-совместимые итераторы? Это нормальный подход что итератор содержит указатель на `Node` (в `std::list` вроде так и сделано, но конечно гораздо хитрее ), если да то как правильно обозначить конец списка и начало? а если такой подход не верный то как сделать лучше?

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176189/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) отвечают на похожий вопрос, но ответ мне не нравится по приведенным выше причинам, так что это не дубликат.

Comment: Никак не могу понять логику использования std::shared_ptr  и почему так много вопросов в одном вопросе?... Задавайте вопрос или по реализации или по архитектуре. Если по архитектуре, то не нужно  представлять реализацию...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Я конечно извиняюсь, но вы серьезно? По моему это придирка чистой воды. Практически в каждом вопросе на этом сайте требуют либо минимальную реализацию либо свою попытку, что я и предоставил, неужели этот код мешает? По поводу вопросов - вопрос один заданный с разных сторон - подход к реализации итераторов. И ответ может быть дан совершенно однозначный. В логике использования shared_ptr вроде все нормально, но если нет было бы интересно узнать что с ней не так.